# Generate and plot different solutions with NDSolve with different conditions in one line

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a set of equations `pdes` and some initial/boundary conditions `bcs`. These conditions depend on some parameters, which I can group as `n` sets,`bcsi` labeled by `i` where `i=1,...,n`.

When solving the equations (for one single set of conditions) I write

```
sols=NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcs},{y1[x],y2[x],...,yN[x]},{x,xi,xf}]
```

If I want to plot the solution, lets say `y1[x]`, I write

```
ploty1=Plot[First@sols,{x,xi,xf}]
```

Now, if I want to solve the equations for each set of conditions, and then to plot, for example, `y1[x]` again, I would do the following

```
sol1=NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcs1},{y1[x],y2[x],...,yN[x]},{x,xi,xf}]
sol2=NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcs2},{y1[x],y2[x],...,yN[x]},{x,xi,xf}]
...
soln=NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcsn},{y1[x],y2[x],...,yN[x]},{x,xi,xf}]
```

and make plots in the same way, etc, and do the following

```
Plot[{First@sol1,...,First@soln},{x,xi,xf}]
```

to get the solutions for `y1[x]` depending on each set of conditions. Is there a way to construct this plot not solving for each set separately but as a `List` or `Table`, in such a way that just doing

```
Plot[First@solutions,{x,xi,xf}],
```

where `solutions` is the set of solutions for each condition, allows to see how `y1` changes when I change the conditions?

Comment: I would first put the boundary conditions in a table and then use `sol=Table[NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcs[[i]]}],{i,1,n}]` to get the solutions in one table.

Comment: If you're going to be varying the boundary conditions a lot, you might want to use `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First put the conditions in a table

```
bcst={bcs1,...bcsn}
```

As suggested above, to solve the equations together

```
sols=Table[NDSolveValue[{pdes,bcst[[i]]},{y1[x],...,yN[x]},{x,xi,xf}],{i,1,n}]
```

to plot the curves for `y1[x]` for each condition, we write

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[First@sols[[i]],{i,1,n}]],{x,xi,xf}]
```

Since we have `n` plots, one can give colors to each curve by setting `n` color inside `PlotStyle`